# Fetching table data in to a array and modify some of the column value then inserting in a table

Tags: postgresql

I am fectching table data in "r_gstinf" array.
And then modify "tax_mny" column data with "p_actmny".

Then trying to insert all the columns data along with "tax_mny"  in a table.

But it is inserting only one column data and remaining columns are inserting as null.

How to insert all the coluns data along with the modified column data.

raise info ' r_gstinf %',r_gstinf;           --r_gstinf {"(Acc_96913,1,,\"01/01/2000 00:00:00\",6000,1)"}

raise info 'r_gstinf[i] %',r_gstinf[i];             --r_gstinf[i] (,,,,,5000,,)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gst_schema.gstcal_func 
(p_custno text, p_actmny numeric ) AS $body$
DECLARE
  r_gstinf             gstdatatbl[];
  gstdatatbl_rec gst_schema.gstdatatbl;
  i RECORD;
BEGIN
select array(select row (custno,
                   d_id,
                   tax_in,
                   tax_dt,
                   tax_mny,
                   tax_id))
              into r_gstinf
             from gsttax;

raise info ' r_gstinf %',r_gstinf;           --r_gstinf {"(Acc_96913,1,,\"01/01/2000 00:00:00\",6000,1)"}

            for i IN 1 .. coalesce(array_length(r_gstinf,1),0) 
            loop
              gstdatatbl_rec.tax_mny := p_actmny;
              r_gstinf[i] :=gstdatatbl_rec;
raise info 'r_gstinf[i] %',r_gstinf[i];             --r_gstinf[i] (,,,,,5000,,)
            end loop;
            FOR i IN 1..array_upper(r_gstinf,1)  
          loop
           insert into gstdatatbl
             (select * from unnest(r_gstinf));
        end loop; 
    END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why no use a simple `insert ... into select ...` without the unnecessary intermediate array?

Comment: Unrelated, but: [looping through array elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) should be done using `FOREACH`

Comment: I can not use direct insert because I am modifying the some od the columns data of the array.
As below.

gstdatatbl_rec.tax_mny := p_actmny;

select gnvinttax.ctax(    p_custno          => r_gstinf[i].custno,
                          p_tax_mny          => r_gstinf[i].tax_mny,
                          p_tax_id          => r_gstinf[i].tax_id,
                          p_tax_dt  => r_gstinf[i].tax_dt,
                          p_td_id          => r_gstinf[i].d_id
                          ) into gstdatatbl_rec.TAX_MNY;

Comment: You are only assigning value to gstdatatbl_rec.tax_mny, all the other fields are never initialized. You should add initializations for all the fields in the gstdatatbl_rec, before the INSERT statement, in the first loop.